# Wifi icon is not displaying in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, troubleshooting, wifi-direct

In Settings app -> *Network* category, I am not getting wireless connection section and also the wifi icon is not displaying neither in the top right dropdown menu nor in the network Settings. In the BIOS wifi driver is there, but it's not reflecting in Addition Drivers in Software & Updates. I tried many things like reinstalling the driver and redeploying the BIOS, but nothing worked.

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f0] (rev 01)   
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090] 
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi   
Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
```

Comment: Attach output of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk -d ::0280`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: 0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device
[8086:51f0] (rev 01)   Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi   Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl